# Realm Studio: Bad progress information (DOWNLOAD)

Tags: macos, realm, realm-studio

When connecting to Realm Cloud within Realm Studio on my 2013 iMac, I get the subject error on the Realm Object Server window for my synced cloud realm instance. After clicking 'Connect to Cloud' the ROS window pops up and the status indicator in the top right moves quickly through Checking Availability -> Connecting -> Connected -> Failed before displaying the error.

I am a new user on a basic/free account. My apps, written in XCode and executed on the simulator, do not have any issues accessing the realm. I have tried restarting Realm Studio, restarting the computer, and removing and reinstalling Realm Studio with no change to the problem. I also have Realm Studio installed on a 2015 MacBook Pro, using the same wifi connection, where it works without issue.

Google searches have turned up nothing, for once. Within the RealmSwift pod file hierarchy installed in the local app's source folders there is a bit of explanation of all existing errors, including a bad progress error, but no additional info on what that particular error means or if it is the same as the Realm Studio error. At this point, I am assuming the obvious, that the error indicates some problem with a download connection or speed, but I am at a loss as to how to fix it or why it is not occurring on my other MacBook.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

[Error message window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyvWI.png)

Comment: In the main Realm Studio window, there's a Logs button at the top and then down the right side Show Levels. Set it to Error or even All and look through the logs for the last time you tried to connect and see if there are any errors. Also, ensure your Realm Studio is up to date. What macOS is it?

Comment: The OS is 10.15.3. Realm Studio is up to date. I can't really access the logs, the ROS window appears only briefly before being obscured by the error message, but a screenshot of the log shows only sporadic login attempt errors which I'm assuming are from the app on the simulator. Any other way to check? I looked but didn't turn anything up. Checked the system console and logs and didn't find anything conclusive. The only error reported is a Unix error exception: 17. I do not know if that is related but it occurs in the console frequently with my connection attempts in Realm Studio.

Comment: The sequence you're describing is a little unclear. When you start the Realm Studio app, you should have a button *Connect to Realm Cloud*. When you click it the next window that opens should say *Your instance is ready* with the Getting Started button highlighted. Is that where you're seeing the error or after that? If after, what's the next step and when do you see the error?

Comment: It may help to include a screenshot of the Realm Studio window with the error. Also, have you tried logging out and then back in? There's also files stored on your drive that Realm Studio uses at *~/library/Application Support/Realm Studio*. As a last ditch effort, you can toss the app and that folder and then download and reinstall. Other than that, you can file a bug report with realm... however.... they are taking several months to get back to those. I just got a response on April 16th to a bug report filed January 30th.

Comment: I've covered all the basic IT checks (logging out/in, restarting, reinstalling), and will probably try them all again. When I click on *Connect to Realm Cloud*, the window goes through the normal connection process, the status indicator shows *Connected* and the window displays normally for a few moments, showing the *Your instance is ready* screen. In this short time I can click on the *Logs* button and see the log for a split second before the error message appears. I had to screenshot it to see what was printed. I will add a picture of the error above.

Comment: Ok, followed your advice on removing the Application Support folder and am now connected again. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent. I tossed that out as an answer as well so anyone else having a similar issue will have a solution. If that worked, please accept it so it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things to try;  the obvious restart, then logging out and back in and if that doesn't fix it, as a last ditch effort delete the files associated with Realm Studio.

There's a folder stored at

```
~/library/Application Support/Realm Studio
```

that can be removed.